# Plotting a list containing tuples to a graph

Tags: python, plot, sage

I have a list of tuples like for example

```
[("name1",0.05),("name2",0.034),("name3",0.03)....]
```

I would like to make a graph with a line of these points with

```
y0 = 0.05
y1 = 0.034
```

and

```
x0 = "name1"
x1 = "name2"
```

and so on.

How would I do this in python/sage ?

Comment: Is there some order on the x's? what is the scale (1, 2, ... )?

Comment: No the x's would just be the names and maybe enough appart so the names can be fully displayed on the graph

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([20,21,22,23])
my_xticks = ['John','Arnold','Mavis','Matt']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

helped me a lot